# How can i invoke a tab from another tab in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the android tab layout. I have 4 tabs.My first tab "Home" is a list view.I want to invoke the fourth tab on the click of a list item in my "Home" tab.How can i achieive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put this inside a child activity:

```
((YourTabActivity)getParent()).getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);
```

In the case above, the second tab will be selected. Or if you use tags to reference your tabs, which is recommended, you can use:

```
((YourTabActivity)getParent()).getTabHost().setCurrentTabByTag("MY_SECOND_TAB");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a ListView.onItemClickListener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView av, View v, int position, long id) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(3);
    }
});
```